# Question about "quadrupole radiation" vector potential formula derivation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics, vector-fields, multipole-expansion

I tried to get an expression for $\mathbf A (\mathbf x )$ in quadrupole approximation. After some transformations of Liénard–Wiechert vector potential I got, as in many books, 
$$
\mathbf A \approx \frac{1}{c|\mathbf x|}\int \mathbf j (\mathbf r , T)d^{3}\mathbf r + \frac{1}{c^{2}|\mathbf x|}\partial_{T}\int \mathbf j (\mathbf r , T) (\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf r)d^{3}\mathbf r, \quad \mathbf n = \frac{\mathbf x}{|\mathbf x|}. \qquad (.0)
$$
It's easy to show that first term is equal to $\frac{\dot {\mathbf d}}{c|\mathbf x|}$, where $\mathbf d$ is the dipole moment of the system.

For the second summand I used hint:
$$
\mathbf e_{i}\int \mathbf {\nabla }(\mathbf j x^{i} (\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf r ))d^{3}\mathbf r = \int (\nabla \mathbf j )\mathbf r (\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf r ) d^{3}\mathbf r + \int \mathbf j (\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf r )d^{3}\mathbf r + \int \mathbf r (\mathbf j \cdot \mathbf n )d^{3}\mathbf r =_{right} = 0,
$$
so
$$
\partial_{T}\int \mathbf j (\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf r )d^{3}\mathbf r = -\partial_{T}\int (\nabla \mathbf j )\mathbf r (\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf r ) d^{3}\mathbf r - \partial_{T}\int \mathbf r (\mathbf j \cdot \mathbf n )d^{3}\mathbf r = 
$$
$$
= \partial^{2}_{T}\int \rho (\mathbf r, T)(\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf r )\mathbf r d^{3}\mathbf r - \partial_{T}\int \mathbf r (\mathbf j \cdot \mathbf n )d^{3}\mathbf r = 
$$
$$
=\partial^{2}_{T}\int \rho (\mathbf r, T)(\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf r )\mathbf r d^{3}\mathbf r - \frac{1}{2}\partial_{T}\left[\mathbf n \times \left[\int [\mathbf r \times \mathbf j ] d^{3}\mathbf r\right] \right] =
$$
$$
= \partial^{2}_{T}\int \rho (\mathbf r, T)(\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf r )\mathbf r d^{3}\mathbf r + c[\dot {\mathbf m} \times \mathbf n ], \qquad (.1)
$$
where I used easy-derived equivalence $\int \mathbf r (\mathbf j \cdot \mathbf n )d^{3}\mathbf r = \frac{1}{2}\left[\mathbf n \times \left[\int [\mathbf r \times \mathbf j ] d^{3}\mathbf r\right] \right]$, and $\mathbf m = \frac{1}{2c}\int [\mathbf r \times \mathbf j]d^{3}\mathbf r$ is the magnetic moment of the system.

The first summand of $(.1)$ can be transformed as
$$
\partial^{2}_{T}\int \rho (\mathbf r, T)(\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf r )\mathbf r d^{3}\mathbf r = \partial^{2}_{T}\int \rho n^{\alpha}r^{\alpha }r^{\beta}\mathbf e_{\beta }d^{3}\mathbf r = 
$$
$$
= \frac{n_{\alpha}\mathbf e_{\beta}}{3}\partial^{2}_{T}\int \rho \left( 3r^{\alpha}r^{\beta } - \delta^{\alpha \beta}r^{2}\right)d^{3}\mathbf r + \frac{n_{\alpha}\mathbf e_{\beta}}{3}\partial^{2}_{T}\int \rho \delta^{\alpha \beta}r^{2}d^{3}\mathbf r =
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{3}\ddot {Q}^{\alpha \beta}n_{\alpha}\mathbf r_{\beta} + \frac{\mathbf n}{3}\int \ddot {\rho} r^{2}d^{3}\mathbf r .
$$
So, I can get from $(.0)$
$$
\mathbf A \approx \frac{\dot {\mathbf d}}{c|\mathbf x|} + \frac{1}{3c^{2}|\mathbf x|}\ddot {Q}^{\alpha \beta}n_{\alpha}\mathbf r_{\beta} + \frac{\mathbf n}{3c^{2}|\mathbf x|}\int \ddot {\rho} r^{2}d^{3}\mathbf r + \frac{1}{c|\mathbf x|}[\dot {\mathbf m} \times \mathbf n ].
$$
But I failed, because the right answer is
$$
\mathbf A \approx \frac{\dot {\mathbf d}}{c|\mathbf x|} + \frac{1}{6c^{2}|\mathbf x|}\ddot {Q}^{\alpha \beta}n_{\alpha}\mathbf r_{\beta} + \frac{\mathbf n}{6c^{2}|\mathbf x|}\int \ddot {\rho} r^{2}d^{3}\mathbf r + \frac{1}{c|\mathbf x|}[\dot {\mathbf m} \times \mathbf n ].
$$
Where did I make the mistake?

**An addition**.

The mistake was in easy-deriving equivalence 
$$\int \mathbf r (\mathbf j \cdot \mathbf n )d^{3}\mathbf r = \frac{1}{2}\left[\mathbf n \times \left[\int [\mathbf r \times \mathbf j ] d^{3}\mathbf r\right] \right].
$$ 
The right one is trivial
$$
\int \mathbf r (\mathbf j \cdot \mathbf n )d^{3}\mathbf r  = \int \mathbf j (\mathbf r \cdot \mathbf n )d^{3}\mathbf r + \int [\mathbf n \times [\mathbf r \times \mathbf j]]d^{3}\mathbf r ,
$$
which leads to the missing factor 2.

Comment: Why my question is tagged as "homework"? If it would be a homework, I would have looked in the book and copied derivation from there (which has differences in details by comparing it with my one).

Comment: The [tag:homework] tag also includes homework-like questions whose main value is the derivation of results rather than the results themselves. For more details see the [guidance in meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715/8563).